# jquery mobile and CSS fixed gradient for every page the same

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I have several pages where I use an gradient as background and an footer which matches the bottom gradient color. Thereby I have a second page which is longer than the dashboard page and the footer mismatches the color. I would like to set an static gradient for each and every page.

As you can see
[image]

This is how I styled the background:

```
.background {
     background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#00cef4,#00a0e5);
     background-repeat:repeat-x;
     background-size: 100% 100%;
     -o-background-size: 100% 100%;
     -moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
     -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

and this is the styling of the footer:

```
.ui-footer {
    background-image: linear-gradient(#00a6e7, #00a0e5);
    border-color: transparent !important
}

.footer a:after {
    background-color: transparent !important;
    /*border-color: transparent !important;*/
    height: 70px;
}

.ui-footer, .footer, .footer li, .footer a {
    height: 70px;
}
```

Comment: Start the gradient from the bottom...simples!

Comment: @Harry That would cause content underneath the footer to bleed through as you scroll the page. @Beginnerprogrammer Have you tried `background-attachment: fixed`? Or sizing background-size with `100vw 100vh` (100% of screen width, 100% of screen height)?

Comment: @Harry that is not working obviously because the icons will be placed in front of content with no background that is not readable.

Comment: @JonUleis I have tried this but only the view will have an background if I scroll down the remaining part is just white

Comment: @Beginnerprogrammer Are you positive you implemented  `background-attachment: fixed;` properly? This would not happen if you did: "only the view will have an background if I scroll down the remaining part is just white"

Comment: @JonUleis `background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#00cef4, #00a0e5);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#00cef4, #00a0e5);
    background-image: linear-gradient(#00cef4, #00a0e5);
    background-attachment: fixed;`

Comment: Oh - just realized you're styling a separate `.background` element instead of the `body` background. That would explain why it's not following in a fixed position as you scroll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try this.
separate the viewport in 2 sections:

html:

```
<body>
  <div class="content">everything goes here</div>
  <div class="footer">buttons go here </div>
</body>
```

css:

```
.content{
  height: 100vh; /* full display size */
  overflow-y: auto; /* everything bigger will scroll like normal */
  padding-bottom: 45px; /* Whatever height you give the icon section */
  box-sizing: border-box; /* this + the padding will make sure your content stops extactly where the footer sta */
}
.footer{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 45px;
}
body{
  /* gradient stuff here */
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The mismatch of the color is not because of the height of the main section & the footer - This part is fine the way you have done it.

Your main problem is the **order** of your gradient colors - **the order of the gradient colors are mismatched to be very precise**.

**Explanation:**

Currently your order is

```
lightest - color 1 - main start
...
..darker..
..darker..
..
darkest - color 2 - main end
lighter - color1 - footer start(this is the mismatch - this should be the same color as the last(darkest))
..darker..
..darker..
darkest - color 2 - footer end
```

So the right order should be(below)

```
lightest - color 1 - main start
...
..darker..
..darker..
..
darkest - color 2 - main end
darkest - color2 - footer start
..even more darker..
..even more darker..
darkest - color 3 - footer end
```

**Solution**

Just **swap the footer's gradient colors** to match. like so

```
.ui-footer {
    background-image: linear-gradient(#00a0e5, #00a6e7); //colors swapped to match main sections color
    border-color: transparent !important
}
```